# Rails appends id to singular route when render edit after errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, routes

I have the following singular route:

```
scope '/seller' do
  resource :seller_profile, :path => "/profile", :only => [:show, :edit, :update]
end
```

and the following controller:

```
class SellerProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :validate_user_as_seller

  def show
     @seller_profile = current_user.seller_profile
  end

  def edit
     @seller_profile = current_user.seller_profile
  end

  def update
    @seller_profile = current_user.seller_profile

    if @seller_profile.update_attributes(params[:seller_profile])
       redirect_to(seller_profile_path, :notice => 'Profile was successfully updated.')
    else
       render :action => "edit"
     end
   end
end
```

I use a singular route given that the user must be authenticated before gaining access to the controller and therefore I can get the seller_profile from the user logged in.

This works like a charm, with only one problem. When I edit the seller_profile and validation error happen, the form is edited again and the errors are displayed correctly. The problem is that rails appends to the url the id of the edited record. For instance,
when I first edit the record, the url is:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/seller/profile/edit
```

but if the form is submitted with validation errors, the form itself is redisplayed under

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/seller/profile.2
```

where 2 is the ID of the record being edited.

The form is the following:

```
<%= simple_form_for @seller_profile do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :description %>   
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Everything, as said, works great but I would totally mask the ID in the url. What should I do?

Comment: I suppose this has to do with the URL you use for your form in your edit view. Can you supply that part of the code as well? (The `form_for`... part)

Answer (score 0):

I have not really worked too much with simple_form_for. But it looks like it is guessing your url always as if they were not single resources. You can provide a custom one:

```
<%= simple_form_for @seller_profile, :url => seller_profile_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :description %>   
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```